# Time Accurancy get reduces after Json to DataTable conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datatable

I am implementing one website in ASP.NET. I need to convert Json string to DataTable. i have used Newtonsoft.Json.dll v6.0.8.18111. It gives DataTable form Json string. But It reduces accurancy in datetime datatype fields in DataTable after conversion.

**Code:**

```
string str1 = "[{\"Start_Time\":\"2016-01-21T08:50:16.177\"}]";
System.Data.DataTable dt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(str1);
```

Above code gives me "21-01-2016 08:50:16" value for Start_Time field. But as per need **we want accurate time which should be "21-01-2016 08:50:16.177"**.

**How can i get accurate DataTable from Json String?**
If you have better solution. Please provide me.

Please help me.

Comment: I guess this is just the date display issue; when I try your code ((DateTime)dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]).Millisecond is set to 177.

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar, Thank you for you response. You are right. But i am getting "21-01-2016 08:50:16" result by using  this code : string time= dt.Rows[0]["Start_Time"].ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default date-to-string format doesn't include milliseconds. You can try for example:

```
var time = ((DateTime)dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]).ToString("o");
//2016-01-21T08:50:16.1770000
```

Check out Reference:

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or make an exact date/time string by using custom formatting:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)